# Typehinting custom collection class in dataclass

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-dataclasses, root-framework, cppyy

I have created a custom Python class, for use in dataclasses, that accepts python lists, but internally stores them as a C++ vector (interfaced with CERN ROOT). The type of what is stored in the vector is specified as a string during init. Therefore, this type is not exposed as a type of the instance, and I would like it to be. I wonder if you could give me some clues? The init part of the class looks like that:

```
class StdVectorList(MutableSequence):
    """A python list interface to ROOT's std::vector"""
    #vec_type = ""

    def __init__(self, vec_type, value=[]):
        """
        Args:
            vec_type: C++ type for the std::vector (eg. "float", "string", etc.)
            value: list with which to init the vector
        """
        self._vector = ROOT.vector(vec_type)(value)
        #: C++ type for the std::vector (eg. "float", "string", etc.)
        self.vec_type = vec_type
```

And the class is used, for example, like:

```
a = StdVectorList("float")
```

I would like to ensure with typehints, that the user gives for example, StdVectorList("float") not StdVectorList("int").

Comment: "Therefore, this type is not exposed as a type of the instance, and I would like it to be. " Maybe I'm not following you, but it *isn't* the type of the instance, so why would you like it to be? That would be confusing. Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe a [`typing.Generic`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html) with a `typing.Literal['string']` or am I missing what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'd like to make sure that the user gives a proper type for StdVectorList (such as int or float), in a similar way I could do with list, with x: list[int] = [1].

Comment: To be more specific: currently, in my dataclasses I have:
x: StdVectorList("float") = field(default_factory=lambda: StdVectorList("float"))
But if the user decides to go with his own StdVectorList("int"), it won't be caught by the typechecker. I would like a way to ensure that user provides StdVectorList("float") here.